# How to add apostrophe in front of an integer on x-axis label in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a basic line chart built in Highcharts. My x-axis labels are the years 19, 20, and 21.

I would like to add an apostrophe in front of these integers so they are displayed  instead as '19, '20 and '21.

I have tried doing this through the formatter and looked through the API. There is a lot about adding a comma but not an ' before an integer.

I am trying to do this for the tooltip.

Comment: Not sure if this will help you... https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use double quote:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ["'19", "'20", "'21"]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/75hsdpe2/

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this is not working for me because I am pulling in my data from a google sheet. I have changed the x-axis labels through the formatter function:
 labels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function () {
          return `'${this.value}`;
        },
      },                                                                                                                                     
But this change is scoped and does not apply to the tooltip. Would you have any idea on how to change them in the tooltip?

Comment: Hi @smaraghi, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3h1cwy7f/